# How to prove that the function $\tan(x)1_{(0,\pi/2)}$ lies in $L^p$ for $p\in (0,1)$?

Tags: definite-integrals, lp-spaces

I am attempting to prove that the function $\tan(x)1_{(0,\pi/2)}$ lies in $L^p$ for $p\in (0,1)$. To do this, I want to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)^{p}\,dx$ for various $p$. However, I cannot make the substitution work properly here. I have attempted using the obvious substitution $u=\tan(x)$, but I have been unable to calculate the actual integral from that, probably due to my lack of experience with integration by substitution.

Is my choice of substitution correct, and if so, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: You do not need to calculate this integral; it suffices to bound it, and that is much easier.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I really have no clue.

Comment: $|\tan x| = |\sin x/\sin(\pi/2- x)| \le 1/|\sin(\pi/2- x)|\le \frac{\pi/2}{\pi/2-x}$... Do you really mean to ask if $\tan(x)^p $ is in $L^p$, or that $\tan x$ is in $L^p$. Because if it's the first one, you'd be integrating $(\tan^p)^p$.

Comment: You are correct. I have fixed this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to in your comment. As near as I can tell, the integral of the final majorant you calculate converges for p=1, which does not seem like it would fit with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub. $u=\tan(x)$ gives $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{u^{p}}{1+u^{2}}du}=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{u^{p}+u^{-p}}{u^{2}+1}du}\leq \int_{0}^{1}{(u^{p}+u^{-p})du}=\frac{2}{1-p^{2}}$$ whenever $p\in (0,1)$

Comment: How do you change the bounds of the integral in the first equality? Apart from that, it looks simple.

Comment: I split the interval from

Comment: I split the interak from $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$, then i make the sub. $u\rightarrow \frac{1}{u}$ on the integral over $[1,\infty)$